# XSL count words that contains in sentence with condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to extract the amount of cars that have the work "automat" in the adtext.
The result should be 1 for < 1999 and 1 for >= 1999.
If I remove the following from ad in XSL [regyear < 1999][type = 2], I get all the cars that have the word "automat", but I need that condition to work...with the condition I get 0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="uppgift3.xsl"?>

<autoads>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Honda</name>
        <model>XL 1000 V</model>
        <regyear>2001</regyear>
        <price>129900</price>
        <adtext>2001 Honda XL 1000 V, 8.900 km. h?g vindruta. Pris 129.900kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Nissan</name>
        <model>Almera 1.4S</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>119000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Nissan Almera 1.4S, 5 d?rrar, met, 70.000 km. el.spegel/f?nster, galv. kaross, c.l?s, startsp?rr, airbag, nedf?llb. baks. ABS, ute temp. R/CD, alarm, d.fte, v.s?ten, s/v-hj.  EU-godk. full service, servo. Pris 119.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>5 d?rrrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mercedes-Benz</name>
        <model>C220 Elegance</model>
        <regyear>1995</regyear>
        <price>209000</price>
        <adtext>1995 Mercedes-Benz C220 Elegance, 4 d?rrar, 88.000 km. skinn, klimat/aut, cruise, el.spegel/f?nster, alu.f?lgar, c.l?s, airbag, antispinn,  ABS, ute temp, radio, s/v-hjul, servo, creme skinn. automat. Pris 209.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 d?rrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>S8</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>850000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi S8, 4 d?rrar, 40.000 km. 4x4, Tiptronic-aut., klimataut., ABS, el.f?nster/speglar/s?ten, soltak, c.l?s, servo, airbag, startsp?rr, antispinn, cruise., alu., trnred., sort skinn, mitttarmst?d., sportss?ten, stereo, alarm, s/v-hjul, dragkrok, 17"+18"alu. Pris 850.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 d?rrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Yamaha</name>
        <model>Thunderace 1000</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>130000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Yamaha Thunderace 1000, 11.500 km. R?d/Silver,tankv?ska medf?ljer. 146hk. Pris kan diskuteras vid snabb aff?r. Pris 130.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A4 1.6</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>260000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi A4 1.6, 4 d?rrar, 78.000 km. el.f?nster, ABS, alu. airbag, , klima, ESP, navig. plus, TV, evt. inbyte, power box (+30 HK) medf?ljer. Pris 260.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 d?rrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Jeep</name>
        <model>Grand Cherokee 2.5TD</model>
        <regyear>0</regyear>
        <price>359000</price>
        <adtext>0 Jeep Grand Cherokee 2.5TD, Stv., 38.000 km. A/C, el.f?nster/spegel, 8xalu., c.l?s, airbag, R/CD, s/v-hjul, servo. Pris 359.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>TL 1000 R</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>110000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Suzuki TL 1000 R, 8400 km. Pris 110.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volkswagen</name>
        <model>Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd</model>
        <regyear>1994</regyear>
        <price>85000</price>
        <adtext>1994 Volkswagen Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd, 4 d?rrar, 135.600 km. Eu-godk?nd, airbag, el.taklucka, just ratt, metallic, radio/CD/Kass, s/v-hjul, servicebok, servo, stereo. Fullst?ndig service, 1 ?gare, 6 h?gtalare. Pris 85.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 d?rrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volvo</name>
        <model>850 2.0 LT</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>245490</price>
        <adtext>1997 Volvo 850 2.0 LT, Stv., 122785 km. halvskinn, el.spegel/f?nster/soltak, fj.c.l?s, st.sp?rr, airbag, just.ratt, rails, nedf.baks?ten m.armst?d, ABS, rad/kass, alarm, dragkrok, s/v-hjul, f.glass, met, garanti, servo. Pris 245.490 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A3 1.6 Ambition</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>180000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Audi A3 1.6 Ambition, 3 d?rrar, 88.000 km. s/v-hj. el.f?nster, ABS, f.glass, alu. c.l?s, servo, airbag, rostfri, stilig bil. Pris 180.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>3 d?rrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>K 1200 RS</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>195000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW K 1200 RS, 4.000 km. sidov?skor, bagageften. Pris 195.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1200</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>Baleno 1.6 GLX</model>
        <regyear>1999</regyear>
        <price>175000</price>
        <adtext>1999 Suzuki Baleno 1.6 GLX, Stv., 49.500 km. A/C, el.f?nster/speil, c.l?s, airbag, rails, ABS, stereo, , servo. Pris 175.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>LS 650 Savage</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>29000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Suzuki LS 650 Savage, r?d. Pris 29.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>650</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>GS 500 E</model>
        <regyear>1993</regyear>
        <price>31900</price>
        <adtext>1993 Suzuki GS 500 E. Pris 31.900,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>500</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>520 i</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>387000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW 520 i, Stv., 52.600 km. Skinn, klima, m.f.ratt, el.spegel/f?nster, alu.f?lgar, c.l?s, airbag x 6, antispinn, rails, trnt, ABS, rad/cd, alarm, dragkrok, met, servo, Pris 387.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Triumph</name>
        <model>Daytona T 595</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>115000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Triumph Daytona T 595, 13.000 km. som ny, karbon anl?gg, nya d?ck, extra tank. Pris 115.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>955</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mitsubishi</name>
        <model>Pajero 2.5 TD</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>59000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Mitsubishi Pajero 2.5 TD, Stv. 4x4, dragkrok, servo, mycket utr., ingen rost. automat. Pris 59.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
</autoads>
```

My XSL looks like this

```
<h2 style="margin:0">Antal bilar med automat v&#228;xell&#229;da: <xsl:value-of select="count(/autoads/ad[regyear &lt; 1999][type = 2]/adtext[contains(., 'automat')])" /></h2>
```

Comment: "*with the condition I get 0.*" I get 2: http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combined condition should rather look like this:

```
ad[regyear &lt; 1999 and type = 2 and adtext[contains(., 'automat')]]
```

As already noted in the comments, your example will yield 2 results for this condition.

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: Admittedly it's only a matter of style but I'd guessed it makes it clearer to the OP how his condition works. His version looks like he tried to make XPath work like LINQ which will sooner or later lead to frustration.